# Nginx 404 isn't redirecting correctly, but I have a basic idea as to why

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-status-code-404

Basically my domain just kinda redirects to the homepage if you do https://epicmc.us/nonexistantpage but  https://epicmc.us/nonexistantpage.php works (My 404 error only pops up if there is a .php at the end of the non-existant page) _ Where did I go wrong? How do I make my 404 page always work?

```
 server {
        listen   80;
        listen   443;
        default_type text/html;  

        location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
                index  index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name epicmc.us;

        error_page 404 /404.php;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.php;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
              fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_index index.php;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last argument of `try_files` is an URI for internal redirect. So basically any non-existent page (that not ends on php) redirects to `/index.php` which exists I suppose.

So I would change config to:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        listen   443 ssl;
        default_type text/html;  

        server_name epicmc.us;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        error_page 404 /404.php;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.php;

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
             try_files $uri =404;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_index index.php;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

I've removed `location /` because directives there are the same as on server level (`root` and `index`) and there is no need to have `try_files`.

`location = /50x.html` is also redundant.

And I've added `ssl` flag to `listen 443`, cause I can't imagine any reason not to have SSL on default SSL port.

EDIT: I doubt that you need `fastcgi_split_info` with `location ~ \.php$`, so I've removed it too.

Comment: **THANKS SO MUCH DUDE** I tend to overlook the little things, and I'm a newbie to Nginx. I appreciate this it worked.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this one i think you had some redundant references to the 404 pages

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name epicmc.us;
    location ~^(?:ico|mp3|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}


    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```